# use not being recognized Class 'MailChimp' not found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

i am using this [mailchimp-api](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) according to the documentation i should just place

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
```

**directory structure**

- index.php (this is where i call any library i use using `use`)
- composer.json
- vendor (this is the folder that contains all libraries from git and the autoload file)

  -- drewm

  --- mailchimp-api

  ---- src (this folder contains the Mailchimp.php that has `namespace DrewM\MailChimp;`)
- configs (config directory)

  -- functions.php (this file contains the function for mailchimp)

now whenever i call this `mailchimp()` function i get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp' not
>   found

**composer.json file**

```
{
    "require": {
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.4",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "^1.2",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2"
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
require_once './config/functions.php';
```

**functions.php**

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
function mailchimp(){
    $MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
    $result = $MailChimp->get('lists');
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: How did you install mailchimp-api library? I see you mentioned git, did you just get a copy of code and put it in vendor directory? Can you post content of composer.json?

Comment: @Nima i installed it using composer, its included in composer.json

Comment: Did you add correct namespace mapping for `DrewM\MailChimp` to composer.json and run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Nima yes `{"require": {
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.4",`

Comment: Can you show us the part of code in which you include vendor/autoload.php, your `use` statements and where you include functions.php?

Comment: @Nima updated my question

Comment: can you post the `autoload` section of the `composer.json` files?

Comment: I tried this today and could not reproduce errors. Is there a typo in `index.php` line 2? I see you mention a directory named `configs` but in your index.php I see `require_once './config/functions.php';`

Comment: not a typo mistake @Nima what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the function class is not under the autoloader of Composer. You should add in the autoload section of the `composer.json` files as example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "./" },
    "files": ["configs/functions.php"]
}
```

And remove the require_once directive of functions.php from index.php

Hope this help

Comment: anything i can do ? the solution you provided does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to include mailchimp in the functions.php

`use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;`

or you can use

```
function mailchimp(){
    $MailChimp = new \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp($apikey);
    $result = $MailChimp->get('lists');
    return $result;
}
```

and pass the `$apikey` in the class

Comment: now i get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp' not found in

Comment: anything i can do ?